# IFRAME - iphone issue

Tags: iphone, iframe

I had to embed an external web page using an iframe, I found no issue and it is working fine for me.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $uri; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

However a user have informed that in iphones, the "src" url in iframe loads in browser (parent window without iframe) when accessed via iphone.

Can anyone please suggest a suitable solution. The target url is from an external domain .

Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: It's possible that the URL you are loading into your frame is doing some frame-busting....

Comment: It is actually happening only with iphones. Could it be device specific ?

Comment: Yes -- It's entirely possible that that URL has some code that may well detect that it's on iOS, and bust-out of any frames it finds itself in. (maybe post the URL that you are using...?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the addition. The target url has only single js file which you can find at https://drive.google.com/open?id=10nQuMHd5YVPuSCAmxu3GXTKXaZlKaBEb , I am sorry I am unable to publish the URL of actual target page here.

Comment: Also I can confirm that there is no inline JS related to frame busting.